# OracleException does not get caught in C# application?

Tags: c#, exception, odp.net

**Update:** Not directly an answer, but updating to the latest managed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assemblies seems to solve the problem. No further exceptions occurred after performing the update.
But I still have no idea why the catch clause seemed to be unable to catch the exception...

---

Maybe I'm getting something wrong here but it looks like an occurring OracleException doesn't get caught. From time to time I get the following message inside the logs of an small application reading article data from an database table. There's no information about what's going wrong.

```
2018-09-04T14:52:41.05+02:00 TRACE - | / -> ENTER Program:currentAppDomain_UnhandledException 
2018-09-04T14:52:41.06+02:00 ERROR - | | unhandled exception occurred Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException     bei Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.GetOpoErr(IntPtr opsErrCtx, Int32 arrayBindIndex, String dataSrc, String procedure)
   bei Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.GetOpoErrCtx(IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, IntPtr opsConCtx, String dataSrc, String procedure)
   bei Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException..ctor(IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, IntPtr opsConCtx, String dataSrc, String procedure)
   bei Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   bei Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   bei Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Read()
   bei #####.Database.DBAccess.LoadModuleParameters[T](String artikelsn, String modulsn, String serial, IHLogger logger) in d:\dev\#####\DBAccess.cs:Zeile 1949.
2018-09-04T14:52:41.87+02:00 TRACE - | \ <- LEAVE (00:00:00.82) Program:currentAppDomain_UnhandledException
```

The code reading from the database table looks like this.

```
var conn = DBAccess.connect(ADDDataToDB.loginData);
try
{
    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ...";
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":a...
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":m...
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something with retrieved data
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (logger != null)
    ...
```

Why does the exception not get caught inside the `catch` block, but instead gets caught in the `AppDomain`'s `UnhandledException` handler.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? Without diving in too far I would assume that the exception is actually occurring on the line where you init the connection. Try throwing a try/catch around this line and see if the exception get's caught.

var conn = DBAccess.connect(ADDDataToDB.loginData);

Comment: you need to show the full exception detail (by calling .ToString()) on the exception object you got inside UnhandledException.

Comment: Does your catch block rethrow the exception?

Comment: @P.Roe Unfortunaltely the only information are the lines from the logfile. `DBAccess.connect(...)` returns `null` if there was a problem connecting the database, so I think in that case `conn.CreateCommand()` would have failed with an NullReference exception.

Comment: @vc74 No rethrowing. Only writing to error log and setting return value to specified object in order to continue working in calling code. But there's no log message in error log. Exception seems not to be caught and only handled by `UnhandledExceptionHandler`.

Comment: @Steve I'll add this, but the problem is, this kind of exception only happens every three or four days although this part of the code is run ~70 - 90 times an hour.

Comment: @verm-luh do you use threads? Tasks? and whats DBAccess.cs line 1949

Comment: @Steve DBAccess.cs line 1949 is the call to reader.Read() in the code example above. So it seems the problem might be the call to `OracleDataReader.Read()`. This code is run inside a WindowsForms - BackgroundWorker (rather old application). I still can't figure out why the exception is not caught by `catch (Exception ex)...`

Comment: @verm-luh please call .ToString() on the exception you got in unhandled exception method. We need the full exception detail to make an educated guess

Comment: @Steve The log file excerpt is created using an NLog ${exception} layout renderer with `format=tostring`. So unfortunately there seems to be no more information than the text displaying after `2018-09-04T14:52:41.06+02:00 ERROR - | | unhandled exception occurred`

Comment: whats in your catch block? are you rethrowing it?

Comment: @Steve Not rethrowing. Only logging the exception details, but there's no entry. So it seems that the exception is only handled by `UnhandledExceptionHandler`.